# Null Pointer Exception when using getListView() to update a single row in a custom list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to update a single row in a custom list view. I am not writing the complete code because it is too long. Just writing enough parts.

My listview Displays Properly
I also know how to update single row.

Because of null pointer exception I am unable to proceed with my codes.. Please help!!!

**ProductList.java**

```
public class ProductList extends ListActivity {

ListView listProduct;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);
listProduct = getListView();
ProductAdapter productAdapter;
productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(ProductList.this,
                R.layout.productlistview, addedList);
listProduct.setAdapter(productAdapter); 

}

public void updateList(Context context){
        int a = listProduct.getFirstVisiblePosition(); // Here I get Null Pointer Exeption
        Toast.makeText(context,
                a + " is listadapter " ,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**ProductAdapter.java**

```
public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SetGetProduct> {

// initialization codes
//getView() method - This properly displays my custom list view
// On the list view I have an ADD - Button
// On pressing that button a dialog box appears to enter new quantity.
// I want to update the new quantity to the purticular row

final Dialog quantityDialog = new Dialog(context);
quantityDialog.setContentView(R.layout.quantity_customdialogue);
quantityDialog.setTitle("Enter Quantity :");
final EditText et_cus_quantity = (EditText) quantityDialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.et_cusdialog_quantity);
                Button btn_quantityOK = (Button) quantityDialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.btn_custom_quantityOK);
btn_quantityOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

quantityDialog.dismiss();
new ProductList().updateList(context);

}
}

}
```

Comment: Post your logcat error.

Comment: **"new ProductList().updateList(context);"** - `ProductList` is an `Activity`. You can NOT create an instance of an `Activity` using `new`. Make your `ProductAdapter` class an inner class of `ProductList` and it will be able to call the `updateList()` method. You also won't need to pass a `Context` as a parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create an instance of `Activity/ListActivity` using `new operator` and access it.

`new ProductList().updateList(context);` // This is wrong way to access Activity instance

Instead you can update your ListView row in the Adapter class itself inside `getView()` method.

OR

You can pass the instance of `Activity` in your Adapter class in its constructor to acess it.

Comment: ViewGroup parent was receiving in getView(). I used the same to get the listView. Thanks a lot. It worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for NullPointerException is:

ListView listProduct; is initialized in onCreate method, and when you are calling updateList mehtod you are creating new instance of ProductList  via new and hence its onCreate method is not called and listProduct is not initialized and remains as null.

One way you can try is create OnClickListener in you ProductList Activity and pass the same to adapter and set it to btn_quantityOK. and from onclickListener call updateList method.

I hope this helps.